# instance of a class inside that class in java

Tags: java

Here i'm declaring an instance of class animal in the same class.
In c It is considered an error:

```
struct demo{
        int anyvar;
        struct demo anyvar1;
};
```

because it is supposed to be an infinite loop of declaration.

Then, Why is this code allowed in Java?

```
class Animal{
    Animal object1 = new Animal();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {     
            Animal obj = new Animal();
            obj.dostuff();
    }

    public void dostuff()
    {
           System.out.println("Compiles");
           object1.dostuff();
    }

    public void keepdoingstuff()
    {
             System.out.println("Doing Stuff...");

             object1.keepdoingstuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Java is a completely different language from C.

Answer (score 11):

Because in Java you're declaring a variable that contains a *reference value*; a pointer.

It's like doing:

```
struct demo{

    int anyvar;
    struct demo *anyvar1;
};
```

All objects in java are created on the heap, and they are explicitly created with the `new` keyword.

```
public class Node
{
   Node next;
   String value;

   public Node() { ... }

   ...
}
```

`next` and `value` are automatically initialized to `null` when a `Node` object is instantiated and will remain so until a reference value is assigned to them.

Comment: Don't want to be picky, but that's *not* why it would throw a StackOverflow error. There's only ever *one* `Animal` object. The problem is that infinitely recurses in the method and blows out the stack. That being said, that's also not what he asked. The fact that the aforementioned behavior occurs at runtime does not make the code "not allowed"; it compiles just fine. His confusion was around the difference between members in a C struct and a Java class

Comment: My intuition says there is at most _not quite one_ `Animal`.

Comment: We're possibly arguing the same point but... If you remove the two methods, and the call to doStuff() you still get a StackOverflow because it can never successfully construct a new Animal, because it is recursively trying to instantiate a itself. In the original example code doStuff() never makes it onto the call stack. In fairness I might have misunderstood the root of the OPs question as I've no experience in C.

Comment: Ha - I see what you're talking about now. In my head I wasn't looking at that because it's irrelevant. The actual question has nothing to do with the class *running*. You'd have to understand C (or C++) to understand the question; his C example doesn't compile for a specific reason that doesn't apply in Java because you always have a reference to an object on the heap, not a local object on the stack.

Comment: Ah k. Should the question be edited to make it more clear what is being asked then or is just my reading of it? :)